# Kitchen setup for US appliances in Europe/India

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I am relocating to India from US and taking all the appliances along. I understand that a lot of appliances can go toast due to voltage support as India/Europe has 230v range and US appliances work at 110-120v range. For tvs i can get a separate adapter, but how will it work for kitchen where i would need multiple appliances to be plugged in. 
Basically, is there a smarter way to support multiple power points at 110v range which might be located at different locations.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not getting kitchen appliances locally?

Comment: My mom actually did/does this in Hungary, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @threephaseeel mostly cos selling them wouldn't give me anything and buying them would take a lot unfortunately.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [expats.se](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) we have all sorts of questions like this.

Comment: Another complication is standard appliance sizes are different too. You’d never fit a US-sourced split-style fridge or 48-inch Wolf range in a UK kitchen countertop, even if the electrical voltages were the same. Also, potentially incompatible natural-gas safety regulations apply too.

Comment: @tallandroid Are you paying for relocation yourself (or do you care how much is spent)?  If your appliances are cheap/old enough that no one would care to buy them on nextdoor/craigslist/etc., then it is very likely that shipping them internationally would cost more than buying comparable replacements at your destination.  And all that's before you even start with the expense of transformers etc. to actually make them work.

Comment: Are you moving permanently or intend to return to the US someday?  Perhaps store your US items for the duration ?

Comment: @GrandOpener - Shipping from Chicago to India is like $1,500 (20' crate). A lot cheaper than I thought. But then there's the moving fee *to* the crate and then *out* of the crate, and likely other fees here and there. And what you end up with is old appliances that are wrong.

Comment: @grandopener I am moving my house, so the cost of moving few appliances will be minor in this case. It's the cost of maintainance which I am worried about.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the most common solution is to sell your US appliances and buy new in India.

The difficulties and expense of getting transformers etc and making it impossible for others to connect the wrong things is not worth the time or expense. But your money your choice, I’m basing this on the decisions others have made...

And I do have a 230v to 110v transformer for 2500W that I use for certain things but not kitchen stuff.

Comment: Also, consider that when you have rewired your new kitchen to handle your old appliances, (I assume you won't want to live with your extra cables left loose and visible everywhere) you won't be able to buy any *new* appliances in India that are compatible with your wiring. And you will have to restore the wiring to its original state if you ever want to sell the house.

Answer (score -1):

Just a tip: "heat only" two 240V phases gadgets like electric, stoves, but not of the induction type could work just plugged phase-neutral instead of phase-phase because resistence does not care about electric frequency (50Hz vs 60Hz). Usually electronics with embedded power supply should support both voltages (check the label) just motor-equipped stuff won't work well because frequency, in that case, is a matter.

So I agree: "big stuff" like dryer, washing machine, dishwasher are better sold in US and re-buyed.

220V Heat-stuff could usually be used without isssues

Electronics: the power label should be checked, very often it can handle both standards (electronics uses DC and adding "multistandard" power supply enable the maker to sell the same product worldwide).

This is a picture of power supply label that could used on 220/100 50/60":
[image]

Comment: But is using 110V heat stuff on 230V wise? as this is what the OP is planning, not what you address in your answer.

Comment: NO: I say you can use resistive 220/240 60Hz (L-L) stuff on 220/250V @50Hz (L-N) power without issues. I'm NOT saying you could use 110V stuff on 230V circuits. they'd be going to deliver TWICE as heat so some MAY work but the game does not worth pot. You should check (on electronics) the label of the power supply, in many cases I said those are multi-standard (laptops are, mobile phone chargers are, some TVs are). It may not be written on the box, but on the device itself.

Comment: @DDS a 110V device on a 230V will produce FOUR TIMES the heat it was designed for, not twice. That idea won't work. Don't even try it. If you get lucky the device will fail quickly. If you get unlucky, your house will burn down.

Comment: **No**, *you can't do this*.  North American ranges require a neutral because they serve both 120V and 240V loads.  Most of the electronics as well as the convenience outlet will run on 120V.  If you just hook up 220V live and send neutral to the other two poles you will feed 220V (or nothing) into the 120V subsystems and either destroy them or have them not function (ie: your range won't work or will be destroyed and won't work).  North american ranges *must have* 120/240V split phase power.

Comment: Most does not require the neutral so 230V is fine: just READ CAREFULLY whay I wrote: if the label sys 220V it WILL run, otherweise there will be written that it REQUIRES both 220V AND 110V

Comment: @DDS Sorry, that's just wrong.  I defy you to show me a range sold in the North American market that does not require split phase 120/240V or 120/208V power.